# Should git-flow branches be available on bare repository and its clone?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I am attempting to start using git-flow. I have installed and initialised git-flow on my master repository. It is all correct and shows in git.config.

It is linked to a bare repository, and I/others clone the bare repository when working.

However, when I clone the bare repository, the develop branch does not show. And in the bare repository git.config there is no git-flow set up.

If I try to 'git flow init' inside the bare repository it just says 'fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree'.

Please help, I am confused! Should I not be seeing a develop branch on the clones?

Comment: The branches will not show up in remote repositories until you push them.  E.g., `git push origin devel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run git flow on the bare repository. What is *probably* happening is that the `develop` branch has not been pushed to the central repository. On a machine that *does* have the `develop` branch, try the following: `git push origin develop`. The do a `git pull` (or a clone) on another machine. You should see the branch then. Note that you will need to do this push for each of the branches you create that you want to be on the server.